# R question: shapiro.test function not working in dplyr::summarize while other summary functions do

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

When I try to use `shapiro.test` as a summary function on my `R` DataFrame I get the error:

```
df %>% summarize_all(shapiro.test)
Error: Column `A` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 4
```

Here is my setup:

```
df = data.frame(A=sample(1:10,5), B=sample(1:10,5))
df
df %>% summarize_all(mean)
df %>% summarize_all(sd)
df %>% summarize_all(sum)
df %>% summarize_all(shapiro.test)
df$A %>% shapiro.test()
```

**Output:**

```
> df = data.frame(A=sample(1:10,5), B=sample(1:10,5))
> df
   A B
1  1 8
2  8 4
3  5 5
4 10 6
5  7 1
> df %>% summarize_all(mean)
    A   B
1 6.2 4.8
> df %>% summarize_all(sd)
         A        B
1 3.420526 2.588436
> df %>% summarize_all(shapiro.test)
Error: Column `A` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 4
> df$A %>% shapiro.test()

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  .
W = 0.96086, p-value = 0.814
```

What is special about `shapiro.test` that makes it not work vectorized on the columns?

Comment: The function returns a list of class `htest"` of length 4. Try defining a function `sh.test <- function(x) shapiro.test(x)$p.value` and use it in the pipe.

Comment: Look at the error message, and look at the output of your Shapiro test. Summary functions should return single values, the way that `mean` and `sd` do. `shapiro.test` clearly does not. What do you expect to have as the test output in a data frame? The W-stat? The p-value?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over each column using `map` from purrr package as an alternative to `apply`

```
df %>%
  map(~shapiro.test(.))
```

Also consider using `sapply` and `lapply`

```
df %>% 
  sapply(.,shapiro.test)


df %>% 
  lapply(.,shapiro.test)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just got it: `shaprio.test` doesn't return a single number. This however, does work:

```
> df %>% apply(2, shapiro.test)
$A

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.96086, p-value = 0.814


$B

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98396, p-value = 0.9546
```

Also:

```
> f = function(x){st = shapiro.test(x); return(st$p.value)}
> f(df$A)
[1] 0.8139521
> df %>% summarise_all(f)
          A         B
1 0.8139521 0.9546435
```